# Should I transpose a Tensor when feeding it into a CNN

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, pytorch

I am using a custom dataset with images of different sizes in the Lab format (Lightness, a, b) which are feed into a CNN. The input layer has 3 in-channels and so my idea was to split all 3 channels (L, a, b) and feed those into the network. Next I was wondering if each tensor needs to be transposed? My doubt is that it would lose its dimensions which are variable from image to image and I would not be able to reconstruct the image in the end. Any thoughts or ideas how I should normalize the image?

Comment: why would you need to transpose it ? you can resize it and do a lot of helpful transofrms with pytorch but I don't see any need to transpose it. for the Normalization, I ve read papers that disscussed this and usually min-max normalization is used with images so I ll advice you to use it. otherwise you can try z-score method but I don't think it will work better than min-max in case of images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can normalise without the need of transposing the image or splitting it based on its channels

`torchvision.transforms.Normalize(mean=[l_channel_mean, a_channel_mean , b_channel_mean], std= [l_channel_mean, a_channel_mean , b_channel_mean])`

The only required transform is the one that converts the images to tensors : 

`torchvision.transforms.ToTensor()`